# Does anyone know how to communicate with device that support SAE J1939 interface

Tags: c#, .net, j1939

We have a device that support SAE J1939 interface and having issue with finding out how to communicate with. Can someone point the direction. Thanks

Comment: The standard specifies how the devices talk to each other, not how you interface to a device.  Contact the vendor of the device you use for support.  They always have some kind of DLL you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SAE J1939 defines five layers in the 7-layer OSI network model,
> ```
>
> and this includes the CAN 2.0b specification (using only the
>   29-bit/"extended" identifier) for the physical and data-link layers.
>   Under J1939/11 and J1939/15 the baud rate is specified as 250 kbit/s,
>   with J1939/14 specifing 500 kbit/s. The session and presentation
>   layers are not part of the specification.

I would start by looking for an adapter.  This would allow you to then say use a Serial or parallel port  connection and poll the device at a specfic band rate.

http://papers.sae.org/972758e

Answer (score 2):

Try the CAN CIA site for full specs: [CAN CIA](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=specifications)

Answer (score 0):

You need software and hardware to be able to communicate with this device. The most popular tools are those from Vector. CANOe and CANAlyzer are generic applications that will help you. However, they costs a lot of money. Good luck!